# IE is claiming not to recognize the text/javascript MIME type

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

We have been developing a Ruby on Rails application. We have recently re-deployed this application behind an Apache proxy which uses HTTPS.

Since we've done this one of our users gets sent to the following page when trying to use the app: http://shell.windows.com/fileassoc/mimeassoc.asp?mime=text/javascript, which says:

```
MIME Type: text/javascript
Description: UnKnown
Windows does not recognize this MIME type.
```

Does anyone know under what circumstances IE would claim not to know what to do with a `text/javascript` file? It's just this one user so far.

Windows 7 / IE 8 and XPsp2 / IE8

*EDIT* Adding the full HTTP response that IE barfs on

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2011 00:31:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.9
ETag: "a6d7d64e3ca943eabc73db920baa7d76"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Runtime: 0.003257
Status: 200
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Connection: close

window.location.href='https://xx.xx.org.au/AED/sessions/new'
```

Comment: is the user accessing the url via https ... are there any warning messages such as "load some resources are not secured" ... loaded over http, which the user may have clicked "no"?

Comment: Just for kicks, remove all of your headers except for `Content-Type`.  (You can use Fiddler <http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/> to set a breakpoint on loading, and remove them without changing your site or server configuration.)  Let's make sure one of the other headers isn't causing things to get confused.  If that doesn't work, then try removing the charset declaration.

Comment: What IE toolbars does your user have installed?

Answer (score 3):

You should try `application/javascript`.

Comment: according to wikipedia, IE 6 through 8 do not recognize this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_JavaScript

Comment: according to his own answer, it was not due that 'text/javascript' was not recognized. 'application/javascript' is not a proper answer as THIS one might not be recognized by some versions of IE re my previous comment.

Comment: I downvoted your answer and then cancelled the downvote later as I very much dislike being downvoted for trying to help with confusing or complex questions. not the right answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Looks like we've figured it out. It was an error in our application that caused it to send some invalid JavaScript to the browser. It seems Rails handles redirects of unauthenticated sessions to the login page by sending a little JS fragment that looks like this:

```
window.location.href='https://blah.blah.org.au/APP/sessions/new'
```

We had a typo in the ERB for this file that made it send this instead:

```
' %>
window.location.href='https://blah.blah.org.au/APP/sessions/new'
```

What's interesting is that only some versions of IE get confused by this.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon - the Javascript is right now but we're still getting the error on a couple of XP/IE8 machines.

Answer (score 0):

IE should recognise text/javascript (see [for example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/26/mime-handling-changes-in-internet-explorer.aspx), 'text/javascript' is mentioned there). Other factors must be at play. You may try:

(1) you can specify the type directly in the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
```

(2) Is the javascript coming from the same site with same protocol? The user may block content that is not secured when coming from a unsecured address and IE may be just given you a misleading error message.

(3) Because you are now behind apache, are any other headers there that may be confusing IE?

(4) I bet you checked that Rails sets the right location for resources (i.e. it uses the proxy host, apache, not rails).

Answer (score 0):

do the http response headers specify X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff?
if so, ie9 will not execute any script until you do so

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that your javascript content is either not correct, or just not "IE" correct. :-)

First of all, if you are saying its UTF-8 are you certain this is what you are serving? In line with Brad's advice, drop the charset definition and see if the behavior changes.

Also grab a copy of the javascript being returned and try to validate it somewhere. I've seen others report issues where the javascript was corrupted in certain specific ways that caused only certain versions of IE to break. Are you concatenating multiple js file or anything like that? Another example is an accidental %> tag in your javascript file will confuse some browsers.

By grabbing the returned value client side using firebug or chrome developer tools you can be sure the proxy isn't screwing up the headers or the encoding (including gzip).

I've also heard that certain older versions of IE don't handle mimetypes properly in iframes. Are you using an iframe at all?

Last but not least, some antivirus/security software will modify the outgoing request Accept headers (not very nice is it?) tricking the server into thinking the browser doesn't support gzip or something. Can you grab a copy of the outgoing request for the javascript? You want to check for modified request headers.

Comment: Yeah. I suspect that IE is doing some parsing on the returned script to try and determine if it really is JS or not, but I don't know exactly what it doesn't like about it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the `type` attribute of the `script` tag.  HTML5 does not require it, and all browsers understand it to be "their local flavour of JavaScript", which is what you want.  Your page won't validate against the HTML4 doctype, but as long as you know why it isn't validating, I think that's okay.  More important to work than to validate.

Comment: This is not an HTML document. It has neither content type `text/html` nor a `doctype` tag.

Answer (score 0):

http://shell.windows.com/fileassoc/mimeassoc.asp?mime=joke/trickquestion